# Meta Quest 2 controllers become inactive when switching from one scene to another in a Unity VR Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

**1.0 Application goal**: Allowing the user to upload a 3D model and adjust it in real-time (scale and texture) with buttons on a UI Canvas, and then bring that 3D model into another scene (e.g. a Kitchen environment) to adjust it further or move it around.

**2.0 Stack**: Unity's XR Interaction Toolkit, Unity3D, C#, MacOS

**3.0 Problem**: When the user clicks a button to take him to the next scene, the scene is loaded successfully with his 3D model in it, however the Quest 2 controllers stop working in the new scene (they cannot be moved).

**4.0 Thoughts**:

Initially, I got the warning "You have two event systems" infinitely many times in the console, but no errors. If I removed the Event System from Scene 2, the controllers would start working again but the buttons in the UICanvas in Scene 2 would not work. This issue was caused by not unloading the previous scene correctly it seemed, as Unity would keep both scenes active and the Event Systems would interfere with each other.

However, if I used the method "SceneManager.UnloadScene()" the Event System warning would dissapear, but the controllers would still not be working in VR. Still everything would work fine in the Editor. I also tried using SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync() and disabling the EventSystem in Scene 2 and then enabling it after the previous scene was unloaded, with no luck.

I hypothesise the issue to be in the SwitchScene script, which handles moving the 3D Model (Game Object) from one scene to another, loading the next scene asynchronously, and unloading the current scene. It also seems like some of the XR Interaction Toolkit components don't get sucessfully transferred from the first scene to the other. E.g. in the user's uploaded 3D model, the XR Interaction Manager GameObject is removed from the XR Grab Interactable component in Scene 2.

**5.0 SwitchScene script**:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SwitchScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Name of the Scene I would like to load, which is assigned in the Inspector
    public string sceneName;

    // Assigning the GameObject I want to move to the next scene
    private GameObject userModel;

    public void OnClick()
    {
        // Finding the user's uploaded model, which has a parent GameObject named "1"
        userModel = GameObject.Find("1");
        StartCoroutine(LoadYourAsyncScene());

    }

    IEnumerator LoadYourAsyncScene()
    {

        // Setting the current Scene to be able to unload it later
        Scene currentScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

        // The Application loads the Scene in the background at the same time as the current Scene.
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);

        // Waiting until the last operation fully loads to return anything
        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        // Moving the GameObject to the newly loaded Scene
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(userModel, SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName));

        // Unloading the previous Scene
        SceneManager.UnloadScene(currentScene);


    }
}
```

Comment: what about your scenes? what is in them? are there maybe multiple instances of the camera rig? Also why not simply use `DontDestroyOnLoad` on your model? This would automatically carry it over into the next scene ... in general you are loading the other scene **additive** anyway ... why not rather stick to a landing/main scene containing the occulus rig etc a single time .. never unload that scene but only load/unload your other scenes additive?